# You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0). We no longer support global installation of Create React App

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
C:\Users\lg\Desktop> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

up to date, audited 1 package in 216ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

```
C:\Users\lg\Desktop>npx clear-npx-cache
Need to install the following packages:
  clear-npx-cache
Ok to proceed? (y) y
```

```
C:\Users\lg\Desktop>npx create-react-app@5.0.0 reduxapp
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app@5.0.0
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

```
C:\Users\lg\Desktop>npm i tar

up to date, audited 153 packages in 1s

6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

```
C:\Users\lg\Desktop>npx create-react-app@5.0.0 reduxapp

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

I tried to solve it through Googling, but an error seems to occur, and the folder cannot be created.

[image]

Comment: As the docs suggest, use `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: I tried to it, "You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).
We no longer support global installation of Create React App." 
same warning.

Comment: make sure that you're using `npx` and not `npm`

Comment: Which part? I think I'm using npx.

Answer (score 60):

try clearing npx-cache if you recently ran this on older version.

```
npx clear-npx-cache
npx install -g create-react-app react-app
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: doesn't `npx` use `@latest` if it's available? I thought that was the purpose of the command? Seeing that it caches, i'm wondering what's the difference between `npx` and `npm i -g`

Comment: I am using `nvm`, and this one did the trick for me. I had already tried the global uninstall several times with no luck.

Comment: Clearing the cache and then running `npx create-react-app react-app` worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer...

Comment: It's advised to not use the global installation for create-react-app but clearing the cache definitely fixes the installation. After clearing the cache running  `npx create-react-app <project-name>`  works

Answer (score 18):

The below command worked for me,

```
npx create-react-app@latest my-app
```

Answer (score 10):

So these are the steps I did to get it to work:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npx create-react-app@latest my-app-name
```

Answer (score 8):

clearing the npx cache solved the issue for me:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Answer (score 2):

Also what one can do is enter the console as administrator, located in the user's folder, and put this command (in my case I used the NPM one)

npm uninstall -g create-react-app

we uninstall it and then I reinstall it

npm install -g create-react-app

and voila, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**This happens when you previously ran this on an older version**.

Step 1: Try to clear cache by running its command:
**npx clear-npx-cache**

Step 2: General command to create your app:
**npx install -g create-react-app react-app**

Comment: clearing the cache helped. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to latest version release of *create-react-app* (5.0.1) all you need to do is first uninstall the previous version of *create-react-app* by run this command
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
or just update the previous version
`npm update -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue run this code: npx create-react-app@5.0.1 reduxapp
Pay attention to installing the latest version of create-react-app otherwise, it is not working well.